# How can I set "High Importance" on email sent using VBA?

Tags: email, vba, cdo.message

I tried setting a few properties on this object to send an email with high importance, but nothing seemed to work.  Here is what I tried:

```
objEmail.Importance = 2

objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-MSMail-Priority") = "High"      ' For Outlook 2003

objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-Priority") = 2                  ' For Outlook 2003 also

objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:httpmail:importance") = 2

Function Send(sTo As String, sFrom As String, sSubject As String)
    Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        objEmail.From = sFrom
        objEmail.To = sTo
        objEmail.Subject = sSubject
        objEmail.Textbody = emailBody
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "my.smtp.server"
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        // is there a property for high importance, outlook 2007?
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update        
    objEmail.Send
End Function
```

Comment: Does using `objEmail.Fields.Item` rather than `objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item` work?

Comment: Yes I somewhat lost confidence in that answer myself after some further googling.

Comment: Did you find this: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/how-do-i-alter-the-priority/importance-of-an-e-mail-message.html ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked with Outlook and VBA but I still have various cheat sheets and links.  I dug this up; hope it helps!

Try setting the .Importance property in your mail object

```
with myEmail
    'can be olImportanceNormal, olImportanceHigh or olImportanceLow
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal
    .Subject = "Subject line"
    .Body = "Body Content"
end with
```

Comment: Doh!

Somehow I completely missed in your OP that you are using .importance.

Comment: In any case, olImportanceNormal is a built-in constant and should not be in quotes.

Answer (score 7):

.Importance = 2 (for anyone looking in 2015).

Comment: upgrading from 2013 to 2015.. this was the fix

Answer (score 0):

From [Remou's link](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/how-do-i-alter-the-priority/importance-of-an-e-mail-message.html) in the comments, this works for Outlook 2010 via VBA:

```
cdoMessage.Fields.Item(cdoImportance) = cdoHigh
```