# Outlook VBA - change importance of email based on subject line

Tags: vba, outlook

I am quite new to VBA in outlook, only used it with Excel.
I am looking for a solution that sets the importance of an email that's currently in composition to "high" based on exact subject lines.

Something like this:

```
If Subject = "Subject Line 1" Then
Importance = 2
Else if Subject = "Subject Line 2" Then
Importance = 2
Else
Importance = 1
End If
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302036/how-can-i-set-high-importance-on-email-sent-using-vba

Comment: Sets the importance when?

Comment: before I sent the email

Comment: Work with `MailItem.PropertyChange event (Outlook)` [Library reference VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.PropertyChange)